# Target Unreachable error after adding validation

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, facelets, cdi, composite-component

The error `"/resources/components/hostForm.xhtml @25,84 value="#{cc.attrs.host.hostName}": Target Unreachable, 'host' returned null"` occurs after I added

```
 <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="200"/>
```

to an inputText field in a custom tag. Without the validation everything works well.

```
     <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="host" />
        <composite:attribute name="prefix" />
    </composite:interface>
    <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
    <composite:implementation>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="titleCell">
            <h:outputLabel for="#{cc.attrs.prefix}hostName" value="Host Name" />
            <h:inputText id="#{cc.attrs.prefix}hostName" value="#{cc.attrs.host.hostName}">
                <f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="200"/>
                <rich:validator />
            </h:inputText>
            <rich:message for="#{cc.attrs.prefix}hostName" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </composite:implementation>
```

The field is declared as

```
  @Named
  @Produces
  private Host newHost;
```

The custom tag invocation:

```
<my:hostForm prefix="c" host="#{newHost}"/>
```

What do I need to change to get this work with validation?

EDIT:

The Bean already has the `@ConversationScoped` annotation.
Adding a `@ConversationScoped` annotation to the fields leads to this error:

hostForm.xhtml @20,74 value="#{cc.attrs.host.id}": org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalProductException: WELD-000052 Cannot return null from a non-dependent producer method: [field] @Named @ConversationScoped @Produces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the annotations from the attribute to a getter, and instantiate the object by myself. This works.

```
@Produces
@Named("newHost")
public Host getNewHost() {
    if ( newHost == null ) {
        newHost = new Host();
    }
    return newHost;
}
```

https://community.jboss.org/thread/179527

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a scope to it, probably Request or Conversation. What you have is the default scope which is essentially like creating one with `new` everytime you need an instance of it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add ConversationScoped which lead to another error message as described in the updated question. Any ideas?

Comment: I hoped frameworks would reduce the need for boilerplate code ;-) +1 experiments with other annotations lead to issues which were easier to resolve. Thank you.

Comment: Makes you wish for conditional initialization, doesn't it?